# How much of gas prices can be tied to refinery profit margins?

Tags: inflation, price, oil

US President Biden wrote a letter (widely reported, but I can't find an official' copy; see [here](https://twitter.com/Phil_Mattingly/status/1537017413933404162) for full text) blaming fat refinery profit margins for the recent (January-June) rise in gasoline prices. The letter quotes a rise of $1.70 during that period in gas prices.

The letter does acknowledge the role of the war in Ukraine in the price increase, which made me wonder:

1. How much of current gas prices can be reasonably attributed to refinery profits?
2. How much would 'normally' be attributed to refinery profits?

A back-of-the-envelope calculation suggests that, if all oil companies current profits were attributed to gasoline that would account for around $0.85 per gallon (at 19 gal/bbl) using 1Q 2022 data. (So it's at least plausible that refinery profits are a major component.) But this is pretty rough; can anyone do better, and can anyone provide a comparison to show how much is increase vs. normal profit levels?